# Concatenating NSStrings with ints - ARC Error

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.5

I'm struggling with concatenating NSStrings and ints. In isolation the below code works great. It returns "This is a test string with an int 10"

```
int myInt =10;

NSString *newstring =
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"This is a test string with an int %i", myInt];

NSLog(@"%@", newstring);
```

However when I put the below code into my project i get an error: Implicit conversion of int to NSString is disallowed with arc."

```
[_mycrop setTempLeft: (@"left value %i is %i", count, [_mycrop leftValue])];
```

Could anybody suggest where I'm going wrong? Although im passing in 2 variables, to my mind both are essentially the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code "in isolation" is very different from the second code.

You have to use [`stringWithFormat:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringWithFormat_) in the second example too.

```
[_mycrop setTempLeft:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"left value %i is %i", count, [_mycrop leftValue]]];
```

Or with two lines but easier to understand:

```
NSString *tempLeft = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"left value %i is %i", count, [_mycrop leftValue]];
[_mycrop setTempLeft:tempLeft];
```

Some documentation: [Apple String Programming Guide - Formatting String Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Comment: Urgh, that was too obvious. Thanks, thats fixed it. Much appreciated.

Comment: @RichPorter: Not so obvious, in this context, is the meaning of the error you got for the second version of the code. The answer is that what you wrote is a **comma expression**, which evaluates to the last term: `a, b` evaluates both of them and evaluates to `b`; `(a, b, c)` evaluates all three and evaluates to `c`. Thus, your expression evaluated to the result of `[_myCrop leftValue]`, which is an `int`. You had this expression where an NSString object was expected (the argument to `setTempLeft:`). You can't pass an `int` where you need an object, hence the error.